# How can I write this link_to code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 4.2
I'm trying to write the following navigation menu but it's not working:

```
<a href="#" rel="ddsubmenu2" class="bred"> <i class="fa fa-users"></i> About</a>
```

I've tried the following:

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_url, rel: "ddsubmenu2", class: "blightblue", {i-class: "fa fa-home"}  %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_url, rel: "ddsubmenu2", class: "blightblue", i_class: "fa fa-home"  %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_url, rel: "ddsubmenu2", class: "blightblue", iclass: "fa fa-home"  %>
```

None of those work. I can't find any examples of an 'i class'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a block.

```
<%= link_to root_url, rel: 'ddsubmenu2', class: 'blightblue' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-users"></i> About
<% end %>
```